# How do I have to arrange the data to get this ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

Suppose I have six different matrixes like this:

```
set.seed(999)

similarity_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
similarity_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

att_set1_prop_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
att_set1_prop_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

compromise_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
compromise_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
```

How do I have to arrange the data to get the following barplot with ggplot2?
[image]

Note, the bars should represent mean values so for example, the mean value of similarity_context_set1 column 1 is the first bar (target on the image), the mean value of similarity_context_set1 column 2 is the second bar (competitor on the image) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `tidyverse`

```
set.seed(999)

similarity_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
similarity_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

# here I deleted the first set1 in the name
att_prop_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
att_prop_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

compromise_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
compromise_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

library(tidyverse)

# add all matrices in a list. I use lst here since the ouptut is 
# a named list 
lst(similarity_context_set1,
    similarity_context_set2,
    att_prop_context_set2,
    att_prop_context_set1,
    compromise_context_set1,
    compromise_context_set2) %>% 
  # transform to tibble and add column names
  map(as_tibble) %>% 
  map(set_names, c("Target", "Competitor", "Third")) %>% 
  # bind the list to one dataframe, add list names to column by 
  # setting .id
  bind_rows(.id = "name") %>% 
  # transform data from wide to long as it is recommended ggplot 
    input format here
  pivot_longer(-1,names_to = "x", values_to = "y") %>% 
  # make to columns for facetting
  separate(name, into = c("name1", "name2"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>% 
  mutate(name2 = str_extract(name2, "[0-9]")) %>% 
  # finally the plot
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group=x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")+
   facet_grid(name2~name1)
```

[image]

The errorbars can be included by adding this line

```
 stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width=0.5)
```